# Why jstl is not working?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Like in the article , I have placed the following files in WEB-INF/lib folder of my applicaion

- Standard.jar (1.1.2)
- jstl.jar (1.1.2)

in taglib it states that it would resolve uri tag in the TLD of a taglib deployed in a jar file (WEB-INF/lib).

And my application keep throwing errors that it cannot found any tag libs.

When I extracted the Standard.jar\MET-INF  *.tld files under to  WEB-INF\tld folder, It worked and sorted. But still is there a cleaner way I could do it, So I may not need to update that taglibs separately other than replacing it with the new version?

Exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: You should add more details about your problem

Comment: What article are you referring to?

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: apparently a Roseindia.net article or one dated before 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have them in your build path. Placing them in **libs** folder may not be sufficient.
In Eclipse for example: right click on project -> **Build Path** -> **Configure Build Path ...**
Then in Libraries tab add your jars using **Add External JARs** button.

Comment: I tried adding to the build path, but it didn't work out. If I extract   tags from standard.jar file to WEB-INF/tags  it works. Any idea How I can get it to work without having to extract the contents there?

Comment: Try Satyas answer and if it doesn't help post some more information (like error message, when it happens, code that causes it) by editing your question as it is hard to come up with a solution without knowing what the actual problem is.

Comment: -1: wrong solution. They won't end up in webapp's runtime classpath this way.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but it wasn't clear if the problem occurs at runtime without the update.

Answer (score 3):

You should **not** extract the JAR files and clutter your webapp project with its loose contents. Remove them all. You should **not** manually define the taglibs in `web.xml`. Remove them all. You should **not** put them in some random `/lib` folder and fiddle with IDE build path properties. Remove them all and undo the changed buildpath properties.

All you need to do is:

- [Download the zip](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/jakarta-taglibs-standard-current.zip), extract it, open its `/lib` folder and copy `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` files in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder (thus, not `/lib`) of your webapp. A bit decent IDE should already have created the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder for you. You just have to drop the JARs in there.
- Declare the taglibs with proper URI in JSPs as per the [tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). For [JSTL 1.1 Core taglib](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) it's the following

  ```
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
  ```

  *(note the `/jsp` in the path, this is often overlooked because old JSTL 1.0 didn't have this)*

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it out but I'm still experiencing the issue, I have updated the problem. I use eclipse for this project.

Answer (score 3):

You can check file web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

end in file .jsp add

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the taglib's information in web.xml  like :

```
 <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

and this uri name you can use in jap like :

```
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
```

Comment: -1: wrong solution. No taglib declaration in web.xml should be necessary for JSTL. They are already inside `standard.jar`. The problem is only that it's in the wrong place in the classpath or the wrong URI was used.