# JSTL tag doesn't work in my jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have create a maven project and I have to use JSTL.

The problem is that when I import the library it doesn't work. I want set a variable and after I want show the value.

This is my jsp page:

```
<body>
       <c:set var="vehicle" value="car"></c:set>
        <c:out value="${vehicle}"></c:out>
        <h1>$(vehicle)</h1>
</body>
```

The problem is that I don't show the value "car" but I read ${vehicle}.

I think is a problem or depencencies. So my pom.xml is this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>

        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Anyone can help me?

EDIT
this is my stucture folder. D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKRK3.png)

My .jsp code

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>



<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="it.model.OggettoDaVendere" %>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>CRUD</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <c:set var="vehicle" value="car"></c:set>
        <c:out value="${vehicle}"></c:out>
        <h1>${vehicle}</h1>


     </body>
 </html>
```

web.xml code:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <listener>

        <listener-class>it.servlet.CRUDListener</listener-class>

    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CRUDServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CRUDServlet</display-name>
        <description></description>
        <servlet-class>it.servlet.CRUDServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CRUDServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CRUDServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Add the full code of your jsp file and `web.xml`

Comment: @lucumut i edit my question

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579735/why-jstl-is-not-working and also your `web.xml` do not include the servelt version,what I say is `full code`,you do not add full code of it

Comment: @lumacut the solution that you post me is work. I Create folder webapp/WEB-INF/libs and I put the jar jstl.jar and standard.jar. I had the jars to build path but it not work. My .js are in webapp/index.jsp. how I modify my web.xml?

Comment: @lucumt sorry  the solution is not work. I wrong to write!

Comment: In your pom.xml you've set your jstl version number as `${jstl-version}`. Have you defined this value in your pom?

Answer (score 0):

`<c:out>` prints the value you want, you don't need to reference it and then call it, which you're doing with parenthesis `()` anyway, when you call a jstl variable you use curly braces `{}`:

```
<body>
  <c:set var="vehicle" value="car"></c:set>
  <h1><c:out value="${vehicle}"/></h1>
 </body>
```

Comment: Yes I correct with your suggest but the error persist, I put in my question my stucture folder